# PIVOT SQL SERVER issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, pivot, query-optimization

I need some help in implementing SQL PIVOT in my data.

here is query :

```
select a.id_mcm AS ID,b.nama_mcm AS Name,c.nama_ctr AS Place,a.tgl_mutasi AS Move_On
from mcmmutasi as a
left join mcmmcm as b on b.id_mcm=a.id_mcm
left join mcmcenter as c on c.kode_ctr=a.kode_ctr
where a.id_mcm='ATP211004131604'
order by a.tgl_mutasi asc ,b.nama_mcm asc
```

and here is the output of it :

| ID | Name | Place | Move_On |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ATP211004131604 | Sumartini | 2021-10-04 00:00:00.000 | Antapani |
| ATP211004131604 | Sumartini | 2021-12-03 14:33:19.450 | Cikutra |
| ATP211004131605 | Person | 2021-10-06 00:00:00.000 | Place A |
| ATP211004131605 | Person | 2021-10-10 00:00:00.000 | Place B |
| ATP211004131605 | Person | 2021-12-08 14:33:19.450 | Place C |
| ATP211004131605 | Person | 2021-12-23 14:33:19.450 | Place D |

and what im trying to do is to make the 2 Rows become 1.
so this is the desire table that i want to achieve it:

| ID | Name | Place 1 | Place 2 | Place 3 | Place 4 | Move_On(Last One) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ATP211004131604 | Sumartini | Antapani | Cikutra | - | - | 2021-10-04 00:00:00.000 |
| ATP211004131605 | Person | Place A | Place B | Place C | Place D | 2021-12-23 14:33:19.450 |

so its easy to read for user to know the history of Person History/Log.

and i tried to use PIVOT SQLServer while reading and learn about it

but im facing some Errors and completely dont know how to use it.

so can anyone help me and telling me how to achieve that.

here is my Code of PIVOT Query :

```
WITH pivot_data AS
(
select a.id_mcm as id ,b.nama_mcm as name , c.nama_ctr as Place,a.tgl_mutasi as Move_On
from mcmmutasi as a
left join mcmmcm as b on b.id_mcm=a.id_mcm
left join mcmcenter as c on c.kode_ctr=a.kode_ctr
where a.id_mcm='ATP211004131604'
)
SELECT  name,place,move_on
FROM pivot_data
PIVOT (max(id) FOR id IN (name,place,move_on)) AS p;
```

---

Update :

```
"Table where i store history of user move"
CREATE TABLE mcmmutasi 
(
 id_mcm VARCHAR(64)
 , tgl_mutasi DATETIME
 , kode_ctr INT
);

"Table Master (user)
CREATE TABLE mcmmcm
(
  id_mcm VARCHAR(64),
  nama_mcm VARCHAR(64)
);

"Table Master place
CREATE TABLE mcmcenter
(
  kode_ctr INT,
  nama_ctr VARCHAR(64)
);

 INSERT INTO mcmmutasi
 VALUES
 ('ATP211004131604', '2021-10-04 00:00:00.000', 13)
 , ('ATP211004131604', '2021-12-03 14:33:19.450', 23)
 , ('ATP211004131605', '2021-10-06 00:00:00.000', 33)
 , ('ATP211004131605', '2021-12-08 14:33:19.450', 43)
 , ('ATP211004131605', '2021-10-10 00:00:00.000', 53)
 , ('ATP211004131605', '2021-12-23 14:33:19.450', 63);

 INSERT INTO mcmmcm
 VALUES
 ('ATP211004131604', 'Sumartini')
 , ('ATP211004131605', 'Person');

 INSERT INTO mcmcenter
 VALUES
 (  13, 'Antapani')
 , (23, 'Cikutra')
 , (33, 'Place A')
 , (43, 'Place C')
 , (53, 'Place B')
 , (63, 'Place D');
```

as u can see, there is a user moved more than 2 places.

```
I want my final results to look like this ( if it possible):
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| id | name    |  Palce 1 | place 2 | Place 3 | place 4 |  Move_On (Only Last One) |
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | Person  | Place A  | Place B | Place C | Place D |  20-11-2023              |
| 5  |Sumartini| Antapani | Cikutra |  -      |   -     | 214-555-1234             |
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can there be more than 2 rows? if yes, what happens then?

Comment: *what im trying to do is to make the 2 Rows become 1* Pivotting not needed in this task. Simply join 2 table copies by `t1.id=t2.id and t1.datetime<t2.datetime`.

Comment: yes , and thats why im trying to use PIVOT so the table can extend to | place 1 |place 2 | place 3 and so on . @AdrianMaxwell

Comment: what if the rows is more than 2 , can be achieved with that ? @Akina

Comment: Provide complete task, not a small part of it. Show all possible data variants. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3. Also provide precise DBMS name and version, and remove non-related tag(s). *what if the rows is more than 2* Enumerate rows in CTE then join 2 CTE copies.

Comment: ok thanks akina .. i will update my post and try to provide as the link u shared .. @Akina

Comment: "*thats why im trying to use PIVOT so the table can extend to | place 1 |place 2 | place 3*" but do you also require  date1 |  date2 | date3 | etc? because, again, there are limits of what is feasible with the pivot feature **PLUS** for a query to produce an unknown number of columns requires use of "**dynamic sql**". So it is vital to fully specify you requirement with reasonable sample data and a fully worked expected result that is derived from that sample data.

Comment: thanks for sharing  new knowledge,  for date no need to make it date1,date2,date3 , Just date of last move, if we make it dynamic so we should use loop , am i right? so we have to create SP ? #JustAsking :) @AdrianMaxwell

Answer (score 1):

Pivot isn't well suited to this as it appears that you need both MIN() and MAX(), so instead use `group by` e.g:

```
SELECT
      a.id_mcm AS ID
    , b.nama_mcm AS Name
    , min(c.nama_ctr) as old_place
    , (case when max(c.nama_ctr) = min(c.nama_ctr) then NULL else max(c.nama_ctr) end) as new_place
    , max(a.tgl_mutasi) AS Move_On
FROM mcmmutasi AS a
LEFT JOIN mcmmcm AS b ON b.id_mcm = a.id_mcm
LEFT JOIN mcmcenter AS c ON c.kode_ctr = a.kode_ctr
WHERE a.id_mcm = 'ATP211004131604'
GROUP BY a.id_mcm ASC
    , b.nama_mcm ASC
ORDER BY a.id_mcm ASC
    , b.nama_mcm ASC
```

**However** if there are more than 2 rows for any selection, then this group by result may not be what you were hoping for. It may be necessary to provide more complex sample data (and the expected result from that more complex data).

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me a lot, and yes i have some user who already had moved more than 2 places ..  thats why im trying to use PIVOT because i know theres some users moved more than 2 and 3 times . so do u have any idea or reference for me to achieve  that or handle users with more than 3 times moving ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. Note: I've included sample data for someone who's moved a bunch -

```
CREATE TABLE mcmmutasi
(
    id_mcm VARCHAR(64)
  , tgl_mutasi DATETIME
  , kode_ctr INT
);

CREATE TABLE mcmmcm
(
    id_mcm VARCHAR(64)
  , nama_mcm VARCHAR(64)
);

CREATE TABLE mcmcenter
(
    kode_ctr INT
  , nama_ctr VARCHAR(64)
);

INSERT INTO mcmmutasi
VALUES
('ATP211004131604', '2021-10-04 00:00:00.000', 13)
, ('ATP211004131604', '2021-12-03 14:33:19.450', 23)
, ('ATP211004131605', '2021-10-06 00:00:00.000', 33)
, ('ATP211004131605', '2021-12-08 14:33:19.450', 43)
, ('ATP211004131605', '2021-10-10 00:00:00.000', 53)
, ('ATP211004131605', '2021-12-23 14:33:19.450', 63);

INSERT INTO mcmmcm
VALUES
('ATP211004131604', 'Sumartini')
, ('ATP211004131605', 'Person');

INSERT INTO mcmcenter
VALUES
(13, 'Antapani')
, (23, 'Cikutra')
, (33, 'Place A')
, (43, 'Place C')
, (53, 'Place B')
, (63, 'Place D');
```

```
SELECT a.id_mcm AS ID
     , b.nama_mcm AS Name
     , c.nama_ctr AS Place
     , a.tgl_mutasi AS Move_On
FROM mcmmutasi AS a
    LEFT JOIN mcmmcm AS b
        ON b.id_mcm = a.id_mcm
    LEFT JOIN mcmcenter AS c
        ON c.kode_ctr = a.kode_ctr
--WHERE a.id_mcm = 'ATP211004131604'
ORDER BY a.tgl_mutasi ASC
       , b.nama_mcm ASC;
```

| ID | Name | Place | Move_On |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ATP211004131604 | Sumartini | Antapani | 2021-10-04 00:00:00.000 |
| ATP211004131605 | Person | Place A | 2021-10-06 00:00:00.000 |
| ATP211004131605 | Person | Place B | 2021-10-10 00:00:00.000 |
| ATP211004131604 | Sumartini | Cikutra | 2021-12-03 14:33:19.450 |
| ATP211004131605 | Person | Place C | 2021-12-08 14:33:19.450 |
| ATP211004131605 | Person | Place D | 2021-12-23 14:33:19.450 |

There are many ways to do a dynamic pivot; here is one such implementation for SQL 2017 and later.

Dynamic pivots dynamically select a column list for your given data depending on your dataset. The reason we use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for the `@sql` variable is because the `sp_executesql` stored procedure requires that exact type.

The CTE 'x' that is used below determines the maximum number of distinct rows for all id_mcm values. If there are 5 persons, 2 have moved once, 1 has moved twice, and 2 have moved 3 times, then the distinct rows with be 1, 2, and 3.

These values are concatenated with the word 'Place', and then the `STRING_AGG()` function concatenates them all together into one string ordered by `x.rn ASC` using the `WITHIN GROUP` clause.

The result is stored into variable `@cList` as the dynamic list of columns that will be used in the pivot that is then stored in the `@sql` variable.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
      , @cList NVARCHAR(1000) = N'';

WITH x
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           'Place ' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id_mcm ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NVARCHAR) AS rn
    FROM mcmmutasi AS a
        LEFT JOIN mcmmcm AS b
            ON b.id_mcm = a.id_mcm
        LEFT JOIN mcmcenter AS c
            ON c.kode_ctr = a.kode_ctr
)
SELECT @cList += N'[' + STRING_AGG(x.rn, '], [') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY x.rn ASC) + N']'
FROM x;

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT ID, Name, ' + @cList
              + N', Move_On
FROM
(
    SELECT a.id_mcm AS ID
         , b.nama_mcm AS Name
         , c.nama_ctr AS Place
         , MAX(a.tgl_mutasi) OVER (PARTITION BY a.id_mcm) AS Move_On
         , ''Place '' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id_mcm ORDER BY a.tgl_mutasi ASC) AS NVARCHAR) AS rn
    FROM mcmmutasi AS a
        LEFT JOIN mcmmcm AS b
            ON b.id_mcm = a.id_mcm
        LEFT JOIN mcmcenter AS c
            ON c.kode_ctr = a.kode_ctr
) AS X
PIVOT
(
    MAX(place)
    FOR rn IN (' + @cList + N')
) p';

EXEC (@sql);
```

| ID | Name | Place 1 | Place 2 | Place 3 | Place 4 | Move_On |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ATP211004131604 | Sumartini | Antapani | Cikutra | *null* | *null* | 2021-12-03 14:33:19.450 |
| ATP211004131605 | Person | Place A | Place B | Place C | Place D | 2021-12-23 14:33:19.450 |

You can put that in a stored procedure or just run it as code. It will detect the number of columns to pivot and do so.

[DB fiddle for reference](https://dbfiddle.uk/U_CuWK-K)

Comment: thnx for including simple data, is it possible if we make (Person ) in 1 row .. i mean like inline, | Person | Place A | Place B | Place C | ?

Comment: You would need to use a dynamic pivot for that unless you could specify a maximum amount of times someone has moved. If the maximum number of moves is 4, then 4 would apply for all users. But if there is one person who moved 20 times, that one person would have 20 columns filled, while the rest had nulls.

Comment: and to use dynamic pivot i should use SP ? right? , lemme say max of move is 5 ,, so no more dynamic columns , how i can achieve it  ?

Comment: Try that implementation. If you wanted to specify one id_mcm, just add a where clause to both queries under each of the left joins.

Comment: i tried that but why row number of place is random ? place1 |place 5|place 3|place 4|place6|place 2| . i tried to change the order by but it doesn't work . one more thing would u mind if u add some explanation as a comment, so me and other people can understand every proses or logic of the query uve made. :)

Comment: I’ll go through it, but row number of place is based on ascending order of move_on date. For the order you describe, I don’t have the data to see what you are seeing.

Comment: @Jafar this last edit should give you everything you need.